# Insertar nodos en una lista enlazada mediante recursividad

Tags: java, recursión, nodos

No entiendo una parte del algoritmo en concreto. En la recursividad, debe haber una condición de termino y para llegar a esa condición el código debe ir decrementando o acercarse de una u otra forma.

En este caso tengo:

```
static Node insert(Node head, int e) {
  if (head == null)
    return new Node(e);
  else 
    head.next = insert(head.next, e);
  return head;
}
```

Lo que no entiendo (y acá esta mi principal duda) es que en la segunda iteración
head.next = insert(head.next, e); // da como resultado head = null
luego entra a if (head == null), retorna new Node y vuelve al else

Alguien me podría explicar como funciona ya que he utilizado el depurador de netbeans para ver el paso a paso pero aún así no lo entiendo del todo. De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En general tu método insert tiene la función de ir recorriendo tus nodos, buscando un espacio vacío ósea un null, para lograr esto: la condición inicial verifica si el nodo al que se esta evaluando el null, y si es así en ese momento se inserta el new Nodo, ahora sino es null, utilizando recursividad el método verifica si el siguiente lo es, con `head.next = insert(head.next, e);`entonces ahora el Nodo a evaluar va ser el head.next y se hace el mismo proceso anterior verificando si es null o no y así con los demás nodos hasta encontrar un null, y cuando se encuentra se retorna un new Nodo lo cual se va a igualar al nodo null, haciendo el insert gracias a la recursividad